# Xcode gives error when trying to run on iOS device

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, clang

I downloaded an xcode project from https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen for a free screen recorder to be able to screen record on my ipod touch 4. I have an apple development account, and have created and successfully run an app I created before on my device. The error I keep on getting is this:

> CompileC /Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/Objects-normal/armv7/IASKSettingsReader.o InAppSettingsKit/InAppSettingsKit/Models/IASKSettingsReader.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/tristanrussell2000/Desktop/RecordMyScreen-master
>       setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -iquote /Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/RecordMyScreen-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/RecordMyScreen-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/RecordMyScreen-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/RecordMyScreen-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -IRecordMyScreen/headers -IRecordMyScreen/headers/CoreSurface -IRecordMyScreen/headers/IOKit -IRecordMyScreen/headers/IOSurface -ISAVideoRangeSlider -I/Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -include /Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/RecordMyScreen-Prefix-gvjgoyylnuezqsdwnywpdvsfrepq/RecordMyScreen-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/Objects-normal/armv7/IASKSettingsReader.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/Objects-normal/armv7/IASKSettingsReader.dia -c /Users/tristanrussell2000/Desktop/RecordMyScreen-master/InAppSettingsKit/InAppSettingsKit/Models/IASKSettingsReader.m -o /Users/tristanrussell2000/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RecordMyScreen-cbqfifjhppabcodiaakmucvxfkec/Build/Intermediates/RecordMyScreen.build/Debug-iphoneos/RecordMyScreen.build/Objects-normal/armv7/IASKSettingsReader.o
>   clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/tristanrussell2000/Desktop/RecordMyScreen-master/InAppSettingsKit/InAppSettingsKit/Models/IASKSettingsReader.m'
>   clang: error: no input files
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Keep in mind that I did not create this app, nor write any code or make any changes. I am running XCode 4.6.3, the latest version, and my iPod is running iOS 6.1.3, and the version in the project is set to that.

Any idea why this is happening and how I could fix it? Thanks.

Comment: no such file or directory: '/Users/tristanrussell2000/Desktop/RecordMyScreen-master/InAppSettingsKit/InAppSettingsKit/Models/IASKSettingsReader.m' 

It simply means the project is incomplete, or the author forgot to include a few files.

Answer (score 1):

That repository has a submodule for InAppSettingsKit.

Did you clone this repository, if so you need to also get the submodule: issue these commands from the top level of the repository:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

If you downloaded it directly, then you'll need to manually get the InAppSettingsKit files and add them to the folder.